# How to Query this formula and it's possible to add automatically sort fucntion?

Tags: sql, excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm using this formula below but only show 2 column can I add like 6 - 8 column? and adding more function like sort from A-Z like 0-9 something?

=query(ArrayFormula({{unique(text('RAW'!M:M,"0"))}, {sumif(text('RAW'!M:M,"0"), unique(text('RAW'!M:M,"0")),'RAW'!AV:AV)}}),"Select * where Col2>0")

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet. I assume you can achieve it by single query function using `group by` clause. Use `order by` clause to sort data.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.